# SQL Server full text indexing disabled

Tags: full-text-search, catalogs

I have a SQL Server 2008 R2 server instance where I'm unable to use full text catalogs. It was upgraded from SQL Server 2008. When I go to the database properties of an existing database or try to create a new database the "Use full-text indexing" checkbox is disabled.

Some things that I have checked are:

- Full text search service is installed and started
- Named pipes protocol is enabled
- Full text service is running under local system account
- **EXEC sp_fulltext_database 'enable'** does run successfully

What else could go wrong, because I'm stuck at it?

Comment: Any errors in the error log ?

Comment: No errors...actually in one DB I can use full-text search, while in another I can't